# Continuity of constructible derived category

Tags: etale-cohomology, derived-categories, constructible-sheaves

Let $X_0$ be a variety over $\mathbb F_q$. Denote by $X_n$ its basechange to $\mathbb F_{q^n}$ and let $X=\lim X_n$ be its basechange to the algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb F}_q$.

Let $D^b_c(X_n,\mathbb F_l)$ be the constructible dervied category with $\mathbb F_l$ coefficients. Is it true, that the map

$$colim D^b_c(X_n,\mathbb F_l)\rightarrow D^b_c(X,\mathbb F_l)$$

is an equivalence of categories?

Comment: Shouldn't you start with $X_1$?  Also, is your (2-)colimit defined by a compatible system of $\ast$-pullbacks?

Comment: Yes, the 2-colimit is over $*$-pullbacks.You are right, the notation $X_1$ would be the more logical for what I call $X_0$. On the other hand the notation $X_0$ seems to be standard.